# Dynamically change font asp.net page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a ASP.net page with Buttons,text boxes, anchor tags.
And I want to change font dynamically in entire web site.so i have added the code in master page at Page_Load event.

```
this.form1.Attributes.Add("style", "font-family:DilleniaUPC;");
```

But the font is working for all content except text boxes and Button controls.the textbox and button are asp.net controls.So i want to implement dynamic font in all controls including button and textbox.
can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class like in your style.css which you might be referring to in  your page. A more specific way will be to use a css class and apply that class to your form elements.

```
button, span, input
{
 font-family:DilleniaUPC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first one changes whole doc, second one to show changes only changes #font, all you need is

```
 $('document').css('font-family','DilleniaUPC');
```

```js
  
  $('document').css('font-family','Georgia');
$('#font').css('font-family','Arial');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hello
<div id="font">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to entire page like this

```
<style type="text/css">
    *{font-family:DilleniaUPC;}
</style>
```

Comment: i tried with following code          
<style type="text/css">
    *{font-family:DilleniaUPC;}
</style>
but it is not working for button,Span,textbox and td.Other contents are working fine.Is there any other idea to apply the font to entire page/site with out affecting other styles.

Comment: strange , its working for me , i put it inside `<head><style type="text/css">
    *{font-family:DilleniaUPC;}
</style></head>`

Comment: I Commented the all font family from css.And added the code  "*{font-family:DilleniaUPC;}" in master page Page_Load event.it works fine.
but the code is affected textbox width.Can any on help to Change font dynamically to entire page/site with out effecting existing css.

Comment: here the code i added in page load.

            Page.Header.Controls.Add(
new LiteralControl(
@"<style type='text/css'>
 *{font-family:DilleniaUPC;}
</style>
    "
));

Comment: here is my aspx code. 
<td align="left" valign="middle">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="select-input"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>